How can I include the labels to this tree?
I have problems to include s_i, \psi and x_s_i so that they are not included in nodes and are aligned correctly. 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    circle, draw, % Nodos circulares
    minimum size=1cm, % Tamaño mínimo del nodo
    edge={-latex}, % Flechas para las conexiones
    l=2.25cm, % Separación horizontal entre hermanos
    s sep=0.5cm, % Separación vertical entre niveles
    grow=east, % Dirección del crecimiento (de izquierda a derecha)
    align=center, % Alineación del texto dentro de los nodos
    scale=0.75 % Reducir la escala del árbol
  }
  % Árbol con nodos invertidos (orden creciente de arriba a abajo)
  [1
    [4
      [10]
      [9]
    ]
    [3
      [8]
      [7]
    ]
    [2
      [6]
      [5]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX! Please review your question formatting. The image is not rendering, and the code should be inside a code block (please refer here) for better readability.

A bit rude solution, but it works . By adding names to nodes (where are needed) and labels to the nodes which are the most out of tree, you can get:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\centering
\tikzset{every label/.append style = {outer sep=1.3mm}}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    circle, draw, % Nodos circulares
    minimum size=1cm, % Tamaño mínimo del nodo
    edge={-latex}, % Flechas para las conexiones
    l=2.25cm, % Separación horizontal entre hermanos
    s sep=0.5cm, % Separación vertical entre niveles
    grow=east, % Dirección del crecimiento (de izquierda a derecha)
    align=center, % Alineación del texto dentro de los nodos
    scale=0.75 % Reducir la escala del árbol
  }
  % Árbol con nodos invertidos (orden creciente de arriba a abajo)
  [1, name=n1
    [4
      [10, name=n10, 
           label=right:$\psi^{\omega_6}$,
           label=below:$x_{s_3}^{\omega}$]
      [9, label=right:$\psi^{\omega_5}$]
    ]
    [3
      [8, label=right:$\psi^{\omega_4}$]
      [7, label=right:$\psi^{\omega_3}$]
    ]
    [2, name=n2
      [6, label=right:$\psi^{\omega_2}$]
      [5, name=n5, 
          label=right:$\psi^{\omega_1}$,
          label=above:$s_3$]
    ]
  ]
%
\node[above=5mm]    at (n1 |- n5)   {$s_1$};
\node[above=5mm]    at (n2 |- n5)   {$s_2$};
\node[above=5mm]    at (n5)         {$s_3$};
%
\node[below=5mm]    at (n1 |- n10)   {$x_{s_1}$};
\node[below=5mm]    at (n2 |- n10)   {$x_{s_2}^{\omega}$};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}


Catch as catch can
